# How to pass dropdown value to state/get request? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey react newbie here!

I am trying to use a select/option value from a drop down to be used in a get request { selectedOption }.

I am unsure how to pass the selectedOption into my main state/component to be used in the get request. 
Can anybody point me in the right direction please? <3

Constructor/state:

```
  public constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      documents: [],
      selectedOption: null
    };

  }
```

Get request:

```
 public getDocuments() {

    axios
      .get("https://bpk.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Colour:" + this.state.selectedOption + "'&trimduplicates=true&rowsperpage=100&rowlimit=1000",
        { params:{},
          headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
        })
      ....
 }
```

Render:

```
 public render(): React.ReactElement<IKimProps> {

    let { documents, selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (

      <div className={ styles.kim }>

        <Selecter></Selecter>

        <br/><br/>

        {this.renderDocuments()}

      </div>

    );
  }

}
```

Selector Component (Not in main app, in the main app its a component called <.Selecter.><./Selecter.>):

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'red', label: 'red' },
  { value: 'blue', label: 'blue' },
  { value: 'green', label: 'green' }
];

class Selecter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  };
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Selecter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're setting the state of `Selecter`, but never bubbling that up to the parent class. The general way you do this is via a `prop` passed to `Selecter` that sets the parent state:

`Parent.js`:

```
...
public setSelectedOption(selectedOption){
  this.setState({ selectedOption: selectedOption });
  // or this.setState({ selectedOption }); (whichever works)
}

public render(): React.ReactElement<IKimProps> {
  ...
  <Selecter onChange={this.setSelectedOption.bind(this)}></Selecter>
}
```

Then, handle the passed function in `Selecter.js`:

```
class Selecter extends React.Component {
  ...
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    if(this.props.onChange){
      this.props.onChange(selectedOption);
    }
  };
}
```